# Run sequential commands in Python with subprocess

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, fenics

hope you can help. I need, in my Python script, to run the software container Docker with a specific image (Fenics in my case) and then to pass him a command to execute a script.

I've tried with subprocess:

```
   cmd1 = 'docker exec -ti -u fenics name_of_my_container /bin/bash -l'
    cmd2 = 'python2 shared/script_to_be_executed.py'
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd1), 
              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = 
              subprocess.PIPE)
    process.stdin.write(cmd2)
    print(first_process.stdout.read())
```

But it doesn't do anything. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `-it` flags in your call do `docker`, you don't want them. Also, don't try to send the command to execute into the container via stdin, but just pass the command to run in your call do `docker exec`.

I don't have a container running, so I'll use `docker run` instead, but the code below should give you a clue:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'docker run python:3.6.4-jessie python -c print("hello")'.split()
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

This will run `python -c print("hello")` in the container and capture the output, so the Python (3.6) script will itself print

```
b'hello\n'
```

It will also work in Python 2.7, I don't know which version you're using on the host machine :)

Regarding communicating with a subprocess, see the official docs [subprocess.Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). Since Python 3.5 there's also [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), which makes your life even easier.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You can use subprocess to call Fenics as an application, section 4.4 [here](https://fenics.readthedocs.io/projects/containers/en/latest/work_flows.html).

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/home/fenics/shared -w /home/fenics/shared quay.io/fenicsproject/stable "python3 my-code.py"
```