# Controlling windows command line with python 3

Tags: python, windows

I would like to start a batch file and send commands to that commands line with python.

I tried os module but I did only open windows command line.

For example:

```
import os
os.system('cmd')

// and now in pseudo-code:
cd to directory
run batch file
send commands to that command line
```

Comment: That's not that easy... And as you use *commands line* in a sense that is uncommon, I cannot be sure of your requirements. What is easy is: execute a batch file in a new windows console, or pass commands to a `cmd.exe` running with no window. Passing commands to a cmd windows is still possible but much harder...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `subprocess` module like so:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("Your command here", shell=True)
```

Comment: I have tried but I cannot control the command line after startting the batch file.

Comment: @retryme What specific command(s) are you trying to run? Also, are you sure it didn't work - *note that `subprocess.Popen` won't display any output by default* so it may have worked but you just aren't seeing any output

Comment: this batch file starts an application which can be controlled by command line with application spesific syntex ex: -add object or -enable object.

Comment: Are you trying to execute sequential commands with multiple `Popen` calls. That is a little more difficult - take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722212/run-sequential-commands-in-python-with-subprocess)